# Google Drive: where are my comments?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

The Google API does seem to permit to [create comments and replies](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-comments) on any type of files (including binary files)

Also, I can publicly share a link and grant anonymous users having the link the permission to view and comment this file. This is the case of this [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxMiPUSrDs2EMWVUQkR3cWsxRWs/view) with id=`0BxMiPUSrDs2EMWVUQkR3cWsxRWs`, yet, browsing this url as an anonymous user, I don't really know where are the comments and how to send a new comment.

Using this Drive API, I successfully created a comment:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/comments
```

Using this Drive API, I successfully listed the file comments:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/comments
```

Result is:

```
{
 "comments": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#comment",
   "id": "AAAAA-ZIom0",
   "createdTime": "2017-03-28T17:21:18.008Z",
   "modifiedTime": "2017-03-28T17:21:18.008Z",
   "author": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": "Sébastien Lorber",
    "photoLink": "//ssl.gstatic.com/s2/profiles/images/silhouette96.png",
    "me": true
   },
   "htmlContent": "Hello world",
   "content": "Hello world",
   "deleted": false,
   "resolved": false,
   "replies": []
  }
 ]
}
```

So it seems this file does have a comment.

The problem is that, when using both the Drive web UI, and the Drive Android application, I am totally unable to access the content of this comment.

I can only see the comment appears as an entry inside the file activity log, so the Drive UI does know that there is a comment, but I am totally unable to find a way to read the comment content `Hello world` inside the official UIs.

---

So: am I missing something, or the Drive comment system is only to be considered as a SaaS backend for comments and the official UIs do not care of the comments we created (unless they are special kind of files, like Google Docs files).

Is there any Drive application out there that actually does show Drive comments for any kind of file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Drive Comments:](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/65129?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

> View all comments:
>
> 1. Open a **document, spreadsheet, or presentation**.
> 2. In the top right, click Comments.
> 3. To close, click Comments again.

This issue is in how Google Drive works.  Google drive only displays comments for the following types of files **document, spreadsheet, or presentation**.

While the API may allow you to add a comment Drive wont display it.

Comment: Thanks DaImTo. So what's the purpose of giving the ability to create comments for all files if they won't be displayed anywhere? Do Google plan to use these created comments someday? I can already store those comments on my own DB, which gives me more flexibility on how those comments are managed. I find the situation a bit confusing and the doc lacking of best practices in this regard

Comment: 1. IMO Probably to allow developers to create there own applications to display them.  2. I am not a Google employee so can not claim to know their plans. However I would send in a feature request. Google drive web -> Cogwheel upper right -> Help -> send feedback.    3.  I can contact the drive dev team and mention that they should add it to the documentation on comment.insert. I agree it should be there.

Comment: Thanks I've just sent a feedback linking to this thread. Adding comment UI to any kind of file would be a nice new feature of Google Drive

Comment: Agreed I have pinged someone I know on the team.   But I wouldn't hold your breath :)

Comment: @SebastienLorber I actually heard back.  They believe that comments used to be displayed in binary docs in the Drive UI and that something has changed.   They have agreed it should be mentioned in the docs.

Comment: thanks for the info, hopefully I'm not the only one to have some legacy :D

Answer (score 0):

These comments should now be shown directly in the Drive UI: https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/02/comment-on-files-in-drive-preview-mode.html

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.